# Migrating old table structure to new found enum is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this `alter` statement and `NULL` value columns are not transferred as 'Male' still remains `NULL`:

```
alter table users modify gender ENUM('Male', 'Female') NOT NULL default 'Male';
```

Why is it not working? Do I need to do it in some other way?

Comment: You can try IFNULL() here are the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Comment: for select statement it is enough , but i am looking for full set of migration not leaving single columns as null Daniel. it is very useful suggestion for me and if else i wont found i will go for this solution

Comment: Add a new column, fill it with the desired values using an appropriate UPDATE statement, remove old column, rename new column.

Comment: it will become blank instead of remain NULL. Default works only in the case of new insert

Answer (score 1):

Default value works only in case of New row insertion.

Although you can set these NULL values to default rows using single update command after the alter command to enum as:

```
UPDATE users SET gender=default where gender is NULL;
```

Thanks